# Inferring latent variable distribution from binary data

Tags: neural-network, classification, regression

I want to create a model to infer the behavior of a latent variable. 
As an example, let's assume the latent variable represents the level of extro/introversion of a person.

The level of extro/introversion can be represented with some continuous distribution and can assume values in [0,1].

I have a **binary** training set of facial images of people who are either:

1. Extreme introverts (for which y=0)
2. Extreme extroverts (for which y=1)

Is there a way to model the original distribution (which is continuous, and not binary as the training set)?

Obvious solutions worked poorly:

I have tried training a CNN; a CNN with sigmoid activation for one output neuron + binary crossentropy, modeling this as a classification problem, and it worked very well distinguishing between the two classes, however, when evaluated on people who are somewhere in the middle of the intro/extroversion spectrum (y=~0.5), it performed poorly, assigning levels which are either close to 1 or 0.

I have also tried creating a regression based network, with output neuron with linear activation and MSE as a loss function, getting the same performance.

Comment: It seems as if you train your model for one task (distinguish extreme intro/extro-verts) and then expect it to perform well on a different task (level of extrovertism). Classifiers simply map patterns to classes, they do not necessarily learn some inherent truth about the world. You trained yours on extreme intro/extroverts, but on test time, you supply it with examples from a distribution is hasn't seen before (mildly extroverts), forcing it to extrapolate. Sorry if it comes out a bit harsh, but there's might not necessarily be a modelling solution for a data problem. Will be happy to discuss

Comment: You are perfectly right @ehudk, those were my exact thoughts as well. By putting this question here, I wanted to make sure I'm not missing anything worth trying.

Comment: One possible solution-by-proxy could be to try model the uncertainty. This way you might be able to detect the cases where you supply your model with samples it hasn't seen before. Low certainty suggests mild extroverts. Then you could use the certainty probability and the prediction probability (e.g., multiplying both probabilities) to get a final level-like prediction. Two relevant works on uncertainty in neural nets I can think of are: [Dropout as a Bayesian Approximation](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.02142) and [SelectiveNet](https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.09192). I hope you find it helpful.

Comment: Thanks @ehudk , definitely worth trying.